# load popup with different dynamic URL using jquery

Tags: jquery, popup

can somebody suggest me how to load popup with URL i want the same as it is like pinterest website (https://www.pinterest.com/) . so that it can help to use different URL for Facebook comments .

i m just appending the parameters to the current URL which is not helping for FB comments.

Okay i added my code below :
popup code :

```
<a class="" href="/log/viewlist?id={{$data->id}}"  data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">My modal</a>


<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Event Name</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Details</p>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-comments"  data-width="500"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

    window.location.url = "/log/viewlist?id=" +  $(this).attr('href');
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.fb-comments').attr('data-href',url);

});
```

my page loads with this but facebook data-href is taking this as different url but the comments i do on one popup those comments are appearing on every modal but i want to show the comments which are updated only for that modal popup .

So is there any other way that can load the modal with URL which can take separately for facebook comments .

Any suggestions please . Thank you !

Comment: SO don't provide code writing service, make an effort of your own and post it if you can't make it work

Comment: @LGSon : I have added my code which i m trying to make it work but it is not working.Suggest me any idea !

Answer (score 0):

You can create this effect by bluring the background and then styling your foreground.

```css
.blur {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  background: url(http://hackingui.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/meng2-1980x1000.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#fore {
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:10px;
  background:white;
  border:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="blur">
  <div id="back">
  filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text 
  </div>
</div>

<div id="fore">
  Testing stuff
</div>
```

Comment: I am not asking about the effect . my concern is only about the URL change when the popup loads so it can help me for FB comments plugin integration and even if i access the URL separately  in another tab that popup should appears .